# Regex string to reformat get set in Visual studio?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013, formatting, refactoring

I need to refactor/convert code similar to this:

```
    FontStretch _fontStretchValue ;

    /// <summary>
    /// Set any Fontstrech properties (Condensed, Ultra Condensed, Expaned, etc.) 
    /// </summary>
    public FontStretch FontStretchValue
    {
        get { return _fontStretchValue; }
        set { _fontStretchValue = value; }
    }
```

to:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Set any Fontstrech properties (Condensed, Ultra Condensed, Expaned, etc.) 
    /// </summary>
    public FontStretch FontStretchValue {get; set;)
```

and:

```
    public string TestStyles MyStyle
    {
        get
        {
            return _testStyle;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_testStyle != value)
            {
                this.SetTestStyle(value);
            } _testStyle = value;
        }
    }
```

to:

```
    public TestStyles MyStyle {get { return _testStyle; }set {if (_testStyle != value){this.SetTestStyle(value);}_testStyle = value;}}
```

I am trying to do this with RegEx (search/replace) as I can't find an option in the Visual Studio editor to do this.

I think I understand the concepts of what I want to do, but am struggling with the implementation.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

(Note - in the first case, I am removing unnecessary backing field references and in the 2nd, I am just reformatting the code.)

One part that is making this complex (at least for me) is that the regex needs to account for a variety of ways that the existing code might be formatted over  multiple lines - say with braces on individual lines, possible comments, nested code, etc.  The second option will usually never have anything more complex than this - usually just a NotifyChanged() call.

On a related note - if you know of a tool/feature/whatever that I can get that will do this for me, that would also be appreciated.  But I still want to figure out the regex string as there are other places I may want to use a similar type expression.

Links to prior discussion on this are also appreciated, I did try to search for them first.

Thank you!

(fyi - I was told to make these changes - so discussions on why I should or should not do this are relatively moot.) 
(fyi 2 - I know how to do the opposite of what I need just using VS.)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm not entirely sure what regex flavor Visual Studio uses, so you might have to adjust these regexes a little.

---

For the first one, replace

```
(?sm)^\s*(?<type>\w+)\s+(?<varname>\w+)\s*;(?:[ \t]*\n)*(?<doc>.*?)(?<prot>public|private)\s+(?P=type)\s+(?<prop>\w+)\s*\{\s*get\s*\{\s*return\s+(?P=varname)\s*;\s*\}\s*set\s*\{\s*(?P=varname)\s*=\s*value\s*;\s*\}\s*\}
```

with

```
${doc}${prot} ${type} ${prop} {get; set;}
```

[regex101 demo.](https://regex101.com/r/mC7rH9/2)

---

The second one is more difficult. The pattern I came up with will only work if there are no curly braces in the getter function, and the setter's opening and closing curly braces are indented to the same level, so e.g.

```
set{
    value= 5;
}
```

won't be matched.

To make things worse, I don't think it's possible to remove the line breaks with pure regex. ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/cM8xH1/1))

Be that as it may, the pattern is:

```
(?sm)^(?<indent>\s*)(?<prot>public|private)\s+(?<type>\w+)\s+(?<prop>[\w ]+)\s*\{\s*get\s*\{\s*(?<getter>[^}]*?)\s*\}\s*set[^\n]*(?<i>\n\s*)\{\s*(?<setter>.*?)(?P=i)\}\s*\}
```

Replace with:

```
${indent}${prot} ${type} ${prop} {get{${getter}} set{${setter}}}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It doesn't quite work, but it may give me all I need to get it working.  Will post what I find.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2012 and later use the .Net regular expression syntax.
Visual Studio 2010 and earlier use their own regular expression syntax.

For multiple line matches, you can match line breaks with `\n` for VS 2010 and earlier or `\r\n` for VS 2012 and later. With VS 2013, I've noticed that if I match a line break anywhere in my Regular Expression, all uses of `\s` for matching white-space will also match line breaks. If I don't match a line break, then `\s` only matches white-space other than line breaks.

So, when matching multiple lines in VS 2013, I'll use `\s*\r\n\s*` for the first line break (getting me any white-space on either side of the line break), then subsequent line breaks and associated white-space can be matched using `\s*`.

Example:

```cs
public static int MyMethod(int abc)
{
    return int * 3;
}
```

Regular expression (not tested):

```
Search:
\s*(?<signature>(?:private|protected|internal|public) (static )?int \w*\((\w*\s*\w*,?)*\))\s*\r\n\s*\{\s*(?<line>.*?)\s*\}

Replace:
${signature}{${line}}
```

The above should give you:

```cs
public static int MyMethod(int abc){return int * 3;}
```